# Workaround to hide selected cell using a `Form Control Button` (with disabled ScreenUpdating)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the following workaround code to hide the cell selection on an Excel sheet by selecting a cell that is out of the visible screen area:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
SomeWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This works when I start the macro manually or with an `Active X Button` but when I start using a `Form Control Button` the selected cell stays the same. It also works without disabling the ScreenUpdating.

Where is this behavior coming from when I use the `Form Control Button`? And is there a way to fix this while keeping the disabled ScreenUpdating as well as the `Form Control Button`?

Comment: I create a `UserForm` with a `CommandButton` and placed your code in event `OnClick` and works fine.

Comment: @Blackcat thanks for your reply. Is that a question or a statement? Please note that I'm not working with a UserForm, I'm placing the buttons directly on the sheet.

Comment: This info was needed. i created a `CommandButton` on the `Worksheet` and your code to the `CommandButton1_Click()` event sub on the sheet's code pane and it works there also as it is expected. This is an embedded form object.

Comment: @Blackcat `CommandButton1_Click()` seems to belong to a Active X Button, not to a Form Control Button. Only active X Buttons create the Click-Sub, with Form Control Buttons you connect the appropriate macro manually.

Comment: This third possibility from Toolbars(""Forms") click and place Button on sheet, assigned the macro to it in the pop-up window also move the activecell to the bottom right cell. (only mention macro can only placed to `ThisWorkbook` or in a module.

Comment: @Blackcat meaning that you can not replicate the error?

Comment: I can only reproduce your problem in very specific circumstances - e.g. If I call `End` before this code, or if I try to click the button when I am paused at a breakpoint. 
How have you named `SomeWorkSheet` - are you sure you are looking at the correct sheet in your workbook.
Are you using an Extended Display - if so try moving your Workbook to your primary display and try again - or disconnect from other displays and try again (I know that sounds weird but it really is a thing)